# Servicemix 4.4 & hot deploy

Tags: jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I'm newbie with servicemix 4.x. I've tried servicemix 4.4 and servicemix-fuse 4.4 with both of them I have the same problem. I've tried to deploy samples to the deploy dir and nothing happens. Servicemix runs, I check the log (tail -f servicemix.log) and there's no message about deploying. I've tried to find some docs about hot deploy under 4.4 but I couldn't find anything.
As I can remember hotdeploy worked out of the box with servicemix 3.x, I just copied zips to hotdeploy dir.

Thanks,

Hubi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ServiceMix 4.4 will hot deploy (`<servicemix home>/deploy`) files of two types: OSGi bundles and JBI service assemblies. That is, jar files (and exploded jar files) that contain the extra OSGi or JBI meta-information, OSGI blueprint xml files, and Spring xml files, which it assumes are OSGi. ServiceMix 4.4 will not deploy vanilla jar files as its not clear how you would want it to load them - would you want it to wrap it as an OSGi bundle, guessing at imports and exports...

Its not clear from your question what samples you are having problems with. A quick look at most of the ServiceMix samples seems that most of them are OSGi bundles (Maven packaging == bundle), which all should hot deploy when copied to the deploy directory.

If you know your jar files are, say OSGi bundles, then I'd check the `<servicemix home>/etc/org.apache.felix.fileinstall-deploy.cfg` file's `felix.fileinstall.dir` property to ensure that its configured to pick up from the directory you think. I'd also check that the File Installer and Deployer services are installed in running. Those typically are within the first 30 services installed, and don't show up on an `osgi:list`, so you can try

```
karaf@root> osgi:ls | grep Deployer
```

If you do not see them, check for modifications to the `etc/startup.properties` file - someone may have removed those services...

Hope that helps,

Scott

[FuseSource](http://fusesource.com/)

Comment: Hi, I checked services, both of them are on the list. felix.fileinstall.dir is also fine. I tried to deploy samples from the fuse distribution (original install). I've tried osgi and jbi types. I managed to package them (mvn package) from console and deployed them by hand to /deploy dir but nothing happens according to the log.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using apache-servicemix-4.4.1-fuse-01-11 and hotdeploy works for me for JBI as well as OSGI based packages (zip for JBI and jar for OSGI). 
Try to find your installed packages by running on the karaf console:

```
osgi:list | grep 'YourBundleName'
```

if its there all should be ok, you can install and uninstall bundles using other two commands:

```
osgi:install yourbundlename
osgi:uninstall yourbundlename
```

Once you have your bundle installed you can see the log output by issuing the following command (works only on Fuse ESB from what I know):

```
log:tail
```